# Replacing JS codes using functions in wordpress child theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My question is quite huge and i'm just swinging it with a little luck. You see i have a custom code in my child theme and it needs to override the code from the parent theme to the child theme without overriding it with the filename. If i disable or overwrite the file, all of the functions of the codes of that file inside will be removed.

[image]

This is the code that's in the child theme

[image]

This is the code from the parent theme that's needed to be replaced from the child theme without overwriting the file itself.

Here are the codes i tried so far but no luck.

```
jQuery(function($) {
if (!function_exists('event')) {
    var clicka;
    clicka = event.target.id;
    if (clicka.length > 0) {
        if (!$('#' + clicka).parents('.topmenux').length) {
            $('#user_menu_open').removeClass('iosfixed').hide(400);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `wp_dequeue_script()` parent script and include from your child theme. Copy file code from parent to your file and do changes what you need.

Comment: besides that, is there such a thing as replacing the code from the parent to child by using a function in php?

Comment: you should  replace js file to your. You can`t replace one function from file, replace all file. Copy needed code from parent file to you child and change waht you need.